# How to set/know DateTime class date format interpretion?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a particular loop where DateTime instances are to be generated. My problem is on how does the class interpret the input string.

The incoming input strings are of the format `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Suppose I have `"1/17/2014"`, DateTime would interpret this as `MM/dd/yyyy`.

But if I have `"6/5/2014"`, how will I be sure that DateTime will parse this with the format `MM/dd/yyyy` and **not** `dd/MM/yyyy`?

EDIT: Inputs may come with the month and/or day in one- or two-digit format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the dates could come in either `MM/dd/yyyy` or `M/d/yyyy` then the overload that takes a `string[]` is the most appropriate:

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input,
    new[] { "M/d/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy" },
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Now, regardless of the zero-padding it will work as expected.

Comment: If the input string now becomes of the format `MM/dd/yyyy` or `M/dd/yyyy`, will the ParseExact function intelligent enough to do the format or will it still go for the specified format argument?

Comment: @solitude, let me edit my answer for that, there's another overload better suited for it.

Comment: @solitude, please see my edit; the code is setup with an array of valid formats.

Comment: I see. A couple of follow-up questions: (1) Is the evaluation of the overloaded argument from left to right? And (2) can you tell me what's that particular syntax/implementation called? (Is that the thing called anonymous functions?)

Comment: @solitude: I don't know what format is evaluated first, and this is simply an overload of the `ParseExact` method.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ParseExact` function to specify the format :

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("6/5/2014", "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If your input are in **MM/dd/yyyy** format, you will get 06/05/2014 instead of 6/5/2014. You will then have to use :

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("06/05/2014", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Be sure of your input format if you don't want to have an exception.

Comment: But OP says: _The incoming input strings are of the format_ **MM/dd/yyyy** not **M/d/yyyy**

Comment: I used the string in his example. Using **MM/dd/yyyy** would result in an error.

Comment: My only issue about the proposed ParseExact function is this: is it intelligent enough to remove/pad 0s should the two-digit months/days come?

Comment: No it isn't. If you are not sure of the input format you can provide an array with both (or more) format. But at least one will have to match, else you will have an exception. Look here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will allow you to specifically match the string